# How to get a value of the property in jquery?

Tags: jquery

The code looks like this,

```
<a class="foo" title="a"></a>
<a class="foo" title="b"></a>
<a class="foo" title="c"></a>
```

How can I get the second value of title when clicking the second ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/LQtCs/)

Comment: @Ruiwant: You are welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick below the vote counts on the left side of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

```
$('a.foo').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".foo").click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr("title"));

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("title");
});
```